# Solve prohibition and overwriting in a XBRL linkbase

Tags: xml, xsd, xbrl

I have developed a parser for XBRL. I have a problem with the rules of prohibition and overwriting in a taxonomy which I recently parsed:

I referred to the XBRL 2.1 specification while implementing the parser. Now, I am missing some labels and don't know whether the taxonomy or my code is not valid.

Here is the example code of some label arcs separated in two files:

```
File 1: <labelArc xlink:from="de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
            xlink:to="extlabel_de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
            priority="1"
            use="prohibited"
            xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/concept-label"
            xlink:type="arc"/>
<labelArc xlink:from="de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
                xlink:to="label_de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
                xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/concept-label"
                xlink:type="arc"/>
<label xlink:label="label_de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
             id="label_de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
             xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label"
             xlink:type="resource"
             xml:lang="de">Übrige / nicht zuordenbare Miete und Pacht für unbewegliche Wirtschaftsgüter</label>## Heading ##
File 2: <labelArc xlink:from="de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
                xlink:to="label_de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
                priority="0"
                use="optional"
                xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/concept-label"
                xlink:type="arc"/>
<label xlink:label="label_de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
             id="label_de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
             xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label"
             xlink:type="resource"
             xml:lang="de">Übrige Miete und Pacht für unbewegliche Wirtschaftsgüter</label>
```

My parser says that the concept `de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other` has no label, because:

- There are 3 arcs corresponding to that label
- Two arcs introduce an actual label with priority 0 and have the attribute `use="optional"` set
- The first arc is the prohibiting arc because it hat the attribute `use="prohibited"`set
- The prohibiting arc has the priority 1 so all arcs with a lower priority than 1 are excluded from the network which is why the other two labels are kicked out

Here is my problem: The XBRL locator for the first acr points to the last label. Meaning the `href` attribute is `file#label_de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other`. I developed my parser as follows: if IDs or from/to values are identical the rules of overwriting and prohibition apply. Hence, I don't know if the locator changes both label IDs to an equal value or if I have to differentiate between those two if these are in different files...?

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Do you have the complete XBRL document and any associated linkbase and schema documents? I am the author of Gepsio (gepsio.codeplex.com) and I would be happy to run the document through Gepsio to take a look for you.

Comment: Yes. You can download the complete Taxonomy here: http://www.esteuer.de/download/hgb-taxonomy-2010-12-16.zip Thanks in advance. I am really struggeling with that one. The ZIP file should contain several folders. The relevant Taxonomy is in the "xbrl/de-gaap-ci..." subfolder...

Comment: Got the ZIP file ... which XBRL document should I be loading?

Comment: the (...)shell-fiscal.xsd in the GAAP subfolder... Thanks again for your help and sorry for the late response. I got caught up in a different project.

Comment: Well, the XSD file is a schema file, which is loaded as a reference to the main XML document. I am looking for the "main", or "root", XML document that represents the top-level XBRL document.

Answer (score 0):

(File 1: labelArc 1) and (File 2: labelArc 1) are indeed [Equivalent relationships](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-RECOMMENDATION-2003-12-31+Corrected-Errata-2008-07-02.htm#_Ref58749019) because the XML fragment they point to is identical (*not because the value of the "xlink:to" attribute is equal*).

(File 1: labelArc 2) is not equivalent to the 2 labelArcs mentioned above because it points to a different XML fragment (the value of the to-attribute is not [x-equal](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-RECOMMENDATION-2003-12-31+Corrected-Errata-2008-07-02.htm#_4.10) and therefore the labelArcs are not [s-equal](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-RECOMMENDATION-2003-12-31+Corrected-Errata-2008-07-02.htm#_4.10) which means they are **not equivalent**). Accordingly, the following label is not prohibited and should be displayed:

```
<label xlink:label="label_de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
         id="label_de-gaap-ci_is.netIncome.regular.operatingTC.otherCost.leaseFix.other"
         xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label"
         xlink:type="resource"
         xml:lang="de">Übrige / nicht zuordenbare Miete und Pacht für unbewegliche Wirtschaftsgüter</label>
```

x-equal means that *not the string values are compared* but the identity of *the XML Fragment they point to*.

I hope this answer isn't too confusing?

Comment: This is interesting, but I just don't get why (File 1: labelArc 2) is not x-equal to (File 1, File 2: labelArc 1). Is it because of the missing attributes "optional" and "use"? If I understand the specs corretly these attributes have default values. If you set the default values (File 1: labelArc 2) is exactly the same as (File 2: labelArc1). Or could you explain again this statement: "x-equal means that not the string values are compared but the identity of the XML Fragment they point to."? If I get it correctly, the location (file it is in?) of the XML fragment (the label) does play a role?